# Events 10000 and 10001 Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, reboot, event-viewer

I can see a lot of events 10000 and 10001 in the Application Logs of the Event Viewer. They relate to RestartManager and if looked closely upon I can see a lot of "StartingSession" and "EndingSession" entries. But no entries to indicate as to why does it keep initiating and closing sessions. Any way to find this out?

I also noticed that my mouse cursor begins to flicker like some operation is being done in the background. The timing with these cursor flickers is correlated with these 10000 and 10001 in the event viewer.

Comment: You are looking at an event log. There will be lots of events of all types. Is there a specific error or issue you are having that has you looking in the Application log? What are you trying to resolve?

Comment: I noticed that sometimes my mouse cursor begins to flicker like some operation is underway. The timing when cursor flickers correlates with these events. Hence why I am wondering

Comment: You need to write your question according to what you are trying to resolve. If you only give us a small piece of the puzzle, we can't be much help to you. Please **[edit]** your post to be more detailed.

Comment: I am trying to find out the reason of these cursor flickers. It is loosely correlated with the events I've described.

I updated my post